# How do I return weekly shift start and end scheduled times in the same row?

Tags: sql

An employee works from 9am to 5pm every day fro 7 days. sometimes the shifts change. so i want to return the whole week's scheduled times in 1 row as this:

I want the following:

```
Sat In           Sat Out          Sun In           Sun Out
---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------
09:00:00.0000000 17:00:00.0000000 09:00:00.0000000 17:00:00.0000000
```

But instead I am getting:

```
Sat In           Sat Out          Sun In           Sun Out
---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------
NULL             NULL             NULL             NULL
NULL             NULL             09:00:00.0000000 17:00:00.0000000
09:00:00.0000000 10:30:00.0000000 NULL             NULL
10:30:00.0000000 17:00:00.0000000 NULL             NULL
```

Part of my code:

```
 Select DISTINCT
             case DATENAME(dw, Date) when 'Monday' then CAST(Start AS TIME)  end as [Mon In]
            ,case DATENAME(dw, Date) when 'Monday' then CAST(End AS TIME)  end as [Mon Out]
            ,case DATENAME(dw, Date) when 'Tuesday' then CAST(Start AS TIME)  end as [Tue In]
            ,case DATENAME(dw, Date) when 'Tuesday' then CAST(End AS TIME) end as [Tue Out]
            ,case DATENAME(dw, Date) when 'Wednesday' then CAST(Start AS TIME)  end as [Wed In]
            ,case DATENAME(dw, Date) when 'Wednesday' then CAST(End AS TIME) end as [Wed Out]
    from Table1 t
        inner join Table2 s on s.ID = t.ID
        where Date between '2020-03-01' AND '2020-03-07'
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What is your DBMS? What does your query do and what do you want it to do instead? What do the two tables contain? Which column belongs to which table?

Comment: As it is, its returning the start and end times but each day is on a seperate row. I want it to display all start and end times per day for the whole week in the same row

Comment: Please provide sample data.  Its hard to help if we don't have that.

Comment: Posting a broken query without telling us what you are trying to do will not help us help you.  Please read this guide on how to ask question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your query up in a subquery and then aggregate like:

```
SELECT min([Mon In]), max([Mon Out]), min([Tue In])....
FROM (
        Select DISTINCT
             case DATENAME(dw, Date) when 'Monday' then CAST(Start AS TIME)  end as [Mon In]
            ,case DATENAME(dw, Date) when 'Monday' then CAST(End AS TIME)  end as [Mon Out]
            ,case DATENAME(dw, Date) when 'Tuesday' then CAST(Start AS TIME)  end as [Tue In]
            ,case DATENAME(dw, Date) when 'Tuesday' then CAST(End AS TIME) end as [Tue Out]
            ,case DATENAME(dw, Date) when 'Wednesday' then CAST(Start AS TIME)  end as [Wed In]
            ,case DATENAME(dw, Date) when 'Wednesday' then CAST(End AS TIME) end as [Wed Out]
        from Table1 t
          inner join Table2 s on s.ID = t.ID
        where Date between '2020-03-01' AND '2020-03-07'
    ) subquery
```

That being said, if we had sample data (from your `Table1` and `Table2`) we may be able to help get a more performant query using crosstab or pivot (depending if this is Access or Sql Server)

Comment: It has worked perfectly  thank you. Sorry I am new and had restrictions on pasting data on my post. Thank you